# Lifetime issue when using the Any trait to get references to structs containing references

Tags: rust, lifetime, any

I ran into a lifetime problem with a little game. The below code represents a very boiled down version of the update loop.
I need the container mutable reference to get references to other game objects or to create new ones or trigger a functionality.

For that reason, I need the `Any` trait to be able to cast the trait to a struct, so in my `GameObj` trait I added an `as_any` method, but this resulted in a lifetime issue.

```
use std::any::Any;

trait GameObj<'a> {
    fn as_any<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b (dyn Any + 'a);
    fn update(&mut self, cont: &mut container);
}

struct object<'a> {
    content: &'a String,
}

impl<'a> GameObj<'a> for object<'a> {
    fn as_any<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b (dyn Any + 'a) {
        return self;
    }

    fn update(&mut self, cont: &mut container) {
        let val = cont.get_obj().unwrap();
        let any = val.as_any();
    }
}

struct container<'a> {
    data: Vec<Box<dyn GameObj<'a> + 'a>>,
}
impl<'a> container<'a> {
    fn get_obj<'b>(&'b self) -> Option<&'b Box<dyn GameObj<'a> + 'a>> {
        return Some(&self.data[0]);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = String::from("hallo");
    let b = String::from("asdf");
    {
        let abc = object { content: &a };
        let def = object { content: &b };
        let mut cont = container { data: Vec::new() };
        cont.data.push(Box::new(abc));
        cont.data.push(Box::new(def));

        loop {
            for i in 0..cont.data.len() {
                let mut obj = cont.data.remove(0);
                obj.update(&mut cont);
                cont.data.insert(i, obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ee7dd33e3d3bfe7350235992ddee98f)

When I try to build the code, it results in the following error message.
If I comment out/delete `let any = val.as_any();` in the `update` function it compiles fine.

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:18:24
   |
18 |         let val = cont.get_obj().unwrap();
   |                        ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 17:5...
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 | /     fn update(&mut self, cont: &mut container) {
18 | |         let val = cont.get_obj().unwrap();
19 | |         let any = val.as_any();
20 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected &container<'_>
              found &container<'_>
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the declared lifetime parameter bounds are satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:23
   |
19 |         let any = val.as_any();
   |                       ^^^^^^
```

How I can make this work without using `'static`, or why is this impossible?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `Object` and `Container` instead, please.

Comment: Are you certain that you need `Any`? Is it impossible in your use-case to have the functionality you want to trigger on the `GameObj` trait instead of extracting relevant method of specific structs with downcasting?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Jep you are right, i am switching between languages a lot especially Java so I mix up the conventions sometimes.      I thought about that as well but the number of methods would explode and not every object would support them, for example I could trigger method open on a door but this wouldn't make sense for a tile GameObj.

Comment: You don't need to implement every method for every type. Just have `enum GameObj { Door(Door), ... }` and, anywhere you currently downcast to `Door`, instead just `if let GameObj::Door(d) = game_obj { ... }`. Downcasting is almost like "admitting defeat" because you can't take advantage of type erasure when you have to go back to the concrete type, so you might as well just use an `enum`.

Comment: (That said, I suspect you may be going down an awkward and inefficient road design-wise, just based on the example. A principle I have found useful is that in object-oriented programming, objects represent pieces of the machine that solves your problem, not pieces of the problem itself. If you're coming from an OOP perspective, I suggest reading [this  short blog series](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/), and watching [the closing keynote from RustConf 2018, on gamedev in Rust](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aKLntZcp27M).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Any` is [declared](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/any.rs.html#88-111) `trait Any: 'static` and can [only store `'static` types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/).  So in order to make `dyn Any + 'a` a well-formed type, your `as_any` method was given an implicit `'a: 'static` bound, leading to the lifetime error you showed.

If not for this restriction, you would be able to break safety by putting in an `'a` type into an `Any` and getting out a `'static` type, because `TypeId` can’t tell the difference—lifetimes are erased during compilation.  See the [discussion on RFC 1849](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1849) for more information.

You should think more carefully about why you want to use `Any`.  It’s almost never what you actually want.  Perhaps something as simple as an [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-00-enums.html) type of all the different object types you might want to store would satisfy your use case better?

If you really want to use `Any`, then you’ll need to find a way to make your types `'static`.  [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html) (or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html#atomic-reference-counting-with-arct), if threads are involved) is often helpful for this purpose; for example, you could have your `object` store `Rc<String>` (or better, `Rc<str>`) instead of `&'a String`.

Comment: Good answer, one nitpick: `Rc<str>` is usually preferable to `Rc<String>` because it has less indirection and you can't mutate through `Rc`, anyway, so the capacity is meaningless (same reason one shouldn't use `&String`).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I think I am gonna go with the enum approach I tried it with a the boiled down update loop and it works fine. Nevertheless it introduces a bit of boiler plait code because to call for example update on the enum I have to use a big match containing all used GameObject structs. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Tobi Yeah, the [`enum_dispatch` crate](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.1.2/enum_dispatch/) can generate that boilerplate for the methods that are common to all of them.

Comment: Thank you that looks very promising, I will try it out.