# Rust doesn't recognize that a borrow ends at the end of a loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In the following code, it seems like the rust compiler has a problem with a borrow being dropped at the end of the code's execution. Even if I wrap the for loop in brackets so it has it's own scope it doesn't seem to recognize that the borrow comes to an end.

```
use std::ops::RangeBounds;
use std::any::Any;

pub trait UpdateTables<T> {
    fn apply_first<'a>(&mut self, table: &'a mut T) -> Box<dyn Any + 'a>;
}

struct Drain<R>
where
    R: 'static + Clone + RangeBounds<usize>,
{
   pub r: R,
}
    
impl<T, R> UpdateTables<Vec<T>> for Drain<R>
where
    R: 'static + Clone + RangeBounds<usize>,
{
    fn apply_first<'a>(&mut self, table: &'a mut Vec<T>) -> Box<dyn Any + 'a> {
        Box::new(table.drain(self.r.clone()))
    }
}
    
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
    let mut d = Drain {
        r: (1..),
    };
    
    println!("{:?}", &v);
    for i in d.apply_first(&mut v).downcast::<std::vec::Drain<'_, i32>>().unwrap() {
        println!("{:?}", i);
    }
    println!("{:?}", &v);
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:32:28
   |
32 |     for i in d.apply_first(&mut v).downcast::<std::vec::Drain<'_, i32>>().unwrap() {
   |              --------------^^^^^^-
   |              |             |
   |              |             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
...
37 | }
   | - `v` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:36:22
   |
32 |     for i in d.apply_first(&mut v).downcast::<std::vec::Drain<'_, i32>>().unwrap() {
   |              ---------------------
   |              |             |
   |              |             mutable borrow occurs here
   |              argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
...
36 |     println!("{:?}", &v);
   |                      ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is not the problem. The errors are the same in this reduced example:

```
use std::any::Any;

fn apply_first<'a, T>(table: &'a mut Vec<T>) -> Box<dyn Any + 'a> {
    Box::new(table.drain(1..))
}
    
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8];
    let _ = apply_first(&mut v);
    println!("{:?}", &v);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:9:25
   |
9  |     let _ = apply_first(&mut v);
   |             ------------^^^^^^-
   |             |           |
   |             |           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |             argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
10 |     println!("{:?}", &v);
11 | }
   | - `v` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:22
   |
9  |     let _ = apply_first(&mut v);
   |             -------------------
   |             |           |
   |             |           mutable borrow occurs here
   |             argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
10 |     println!("{:?}", &v);
   |                      ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

The core issue is that `Any` only works for `'static` types, so `dyn Any + 'a` is meaningless and implies that `'a: 'static`. I do wish the compiler was a little more informative about *where* the `'static` constraint was coming from, but I digress.

See also: [Lifetime issue when using the Any trait to get references to structs containing references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503120/lifetime-issue-when-using-the-any-trait-to-get-references-to-structs-containing)

Comment: Good catch. It seems to me that the error message is simply pointing at the wrong method; [`downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) is the one that actually has a `'static` bound.  (The supertrait bound on `Any` requires implementors to be `'static`, but it's covariant, so nothing stops the compiler from shrinking `dyn Any + 'static` to `dyn Any + 'a` when asked, even though such a lifetime is useless with `Any`.)

Comment: @trentcl the reduced example doesn't use `downcast` and shows the same error. `Any` is only implemented for types that are `'static` and `std::vec::Drain<'a, T>` is not, whether or not `dyn Any + 'static` to `dyn Any + 'a` is ok is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I must have posted before I was fully awake. You are right that it's not `downcast`, but I disagree that it has anything to do with `std::vec::Drain` not being `'static`, because the cast to `dyn Any` happens inside `apply_first` but the error is in `main`. [No `drain`, same error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=688ee7bbef7249d1882aab202321d843) Seems that the compiler knows that `dyn Any + 'a` implies `'a: 'static` after all.

Comment: @trentcl oh, I see what you were saying now